# changing the default name of Activiti table name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, activiti, bpmn

I'm using Activiti in my Spring Boot application: 'org.activiti:activiti-spring-boot-starter:7.1.0.M3.1'. By default, all Activiti tables are contained in Spring Boot App database schema - Oracle 12.2 in my case. All Activiti table names start with 'ACT_' prefix and all this tables and its indexes are in default 'USERS' tablespace.
How do I change the default name of Activiti tables?